# How to make Angular 6 application run on IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, polyfills

My application works absolutely fine on Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Safari but on IE 11 the whole UI is blank and there are errors on browser console:
[image]
I did a lot of research. Someone suggested me to add missing polyfills. I did the same:
(sorry for pasting the whole file here)
**polyfills.ts**

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'classlist.js';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/map';
import 'core-js/es7/set';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

**browserlist**

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

> 0.5%
last 2 versions
Firefox ESR
not dead
IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

But still the screen is blank with same errors on console. Please help me out. I'm blocked since last 8 days.

Comment: Your tsconfig states that you compile to es5? If yes then you don't need the es6 pollyfills atleast

Comment: see i have two more files in the question

Comment: also i tried `import 'core-js';` which is not recommended.

Comment: did you try to add the browsers for browserlist to the package.json ?

Comment: @NicolasGehlert, Yes Sir. I've added my browserlist file in the question also. Please have a look.

Comment: What if you remove the pollyfills? Where does it fall

Comment: @misha130, it just keeps on giving me the erros that i pasted in the question

Comment: yes you have it as a separate file. but there's also a property in the package.json for it. in the past angular had problems with the separate file and could only handle the values in package.json @Tanzeel

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this flag before loading zone.js:

```
(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

I found it already exists in the `polyfills.ts` you posted, you need to uncomment it.

And this seems to be a known issue, you can refer to this link: [[BUG] IE11 -> Can't execute code from a freed script](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31723).

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.